# Login Authenticate issue in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I am trying to making a login system where i manually inserted "Email" and "Password" in Database .Because there are no Register System.
Now my password not hashes/encrypted  in my Database.When we will attempt to login Laravel will try to Authenticate user by hashes/encrypted Password.How Solve this issue.Can anybody help me??

Comment: make it encrypted. not just because the authenticate does it, but because it is how it should be for many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Laravel tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan)

ssh into your server. Then:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Find your user:

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

Set the password/email

```
$user->password = bcrypt('yourpassword');

$user->email = 'info@corporation.com';
```

Save it

```
$user->save();
```

Done.